# Titan error when one of the connected Cassandra nodes comes down

Tags: cassandra, titan, astyanax

We have Titan setup with Cassandra as it's `storage.backend`. We have a cluster of 3 Cassandra nodes. We are seeing the following error when one of the Cassandra nodes fail/shutdown.

This is the error that gets logged. Any help on this will be really appreciated.

> INFO CountingConnectionPoolMonitor:194 - AddHost: 10.76.54.7
>
> ERROR ConnectionPoolMBeanManager:74 - com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=KeyspaceTitanConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
>
> ERROR ConnectionPoolMBeanManager:74 - com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=ClusterTitanConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
>
> INFO GraphDatabaseConfiguration:1518 - Generated unique-instance-id=3217005b14357-titan-m21e
>
> INFO ConnectionPoolMBeanManager:53 - Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=ClusterTitanConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
>
> INFO CountingConnectionPoolMonitor:194 - AddHost: 10.76.54.44
>
> INFO CountingConnectionPoolMonitor:194 - AddHost: 10.76.54.57
>
> INFO CountingConnectionPoolMonitor:194 - AddHost: 10.76.54.7
>
> INFO ConnectionPoolMBeanManager:53 - Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=KeyspaceTitanConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
>
> INFO CountingConnectionPoolMonitor:194 - AddHost: 10.76.54.44
>
> INFO CountingConnectionPoolMonitor:194 - AddHost: 10.76.54.57
>
> INFO CountingConnectionPoolMonitor:194 - AddHost: 10.76.54.7
>
> INFO Backend:459 - Configuring index [search]
>
> INFO plugins:151 - [Donald Ritter] loaded [], sites []
>
> INFO ElasticSearchIndex:354 - Configured remote host: 10.76.54.15 : 9300
>
> INFO ElasticSearchIndex:354 - Configured remote host: 10.76.54.24 : 9300
>
> INFO ElasticSearchIndex:354 - Configured remote host: 10.77.170.171 : 9300
>
> INFO Backend:176 - Initiated backend operations thread pool of size 16
>
> INFO KCVSLog:730 - Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2016-02-16T23:45:27.539Z into com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@49f59d47

Comment: Is that the only error, no stack trace below it? Do graph requests succeed or fail at that point? What replication factor do you have set on the graph / keyspace?

Comment: @JeffJirsa, updated the question with full stack trace. The graph request fails at that point. Replication factor is set to 3.

Comment: Just to be clear - is the node down when you startup titan? Is it the only node in the backend config?

Comment: No, all three cassandra nodes are up when titan starts up. After that when one of the cassandra nodes goes down, the above error happens. All three nodes are listed in storage.hostname